# d3.max value is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a nested array like this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":0,"c":1},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1}]
```

and I'm trying to find the max number of the total but I get a undefined value back, and I make sure that I pass an array instead of an object but I still don't get the correct value.

```
     var max = d3.max(scope.data, function (d) {
            return d.a + d.b + d.c;
        });
```

I tried with d3.values to make sure that the value I passed in is an array but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

That will be

```
return d[0].a + d[0].b + d[0].c;
```

because each element in Array is an array and that have an object in it's `0th` index.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your array:

```
[[{"a":1,"b":0,"c":1}],[{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1}],[{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1}]]
```

with this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":0,"c":1},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1}]
```

because each array child is having just one json object, why put it in some array []

Comment: I did this as well, but it doesn't fix the problem which is strange especially when I try it in a jsfiddle, it works

Comment: then you should check your js resources, versions etc... if it works at fiddle.

Comment: oh I did. Everything works just fine, but the max function just returns undefined which is strange to me.